# mysql Unknown column in 'where clause' when using reserved word

Tags: mysql, where-clause

The mytable's column name are key, value, modified_at.
I knew key is a reserved word on mysql.

so I use ``.

```
select * from mytable where `key`=XXX;
```

but failed and return message is

```
Unknown column 'XXX' in 'where clause'.
```

What can I should do to fix?

Comment: Can you show the table structure?

Comment: sure. key = varchar<255>,PRI / value = varchar<255> / modified_at = timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure the XXX is in quotations.

```
select * from mytable where `key`="wonkystuff";
```

Comment: No problem! A checkmark is thanks enough :D (When you get an answer you like, click the checkmark icon under the arrows to the left of this answer. Helps the community out.)

Answer (score 0):

In your query:

```
select *
from mytable
where `key` = XXX;
```

The expression `XXX` is not escaped in any way.  That means that SQL recognizes it as an identifier, and in this context, it would be a column name.

To make this a string constant, put it in single quotes.  You should always use single quotes for string and date constants, and not for anything else:

```
select *
from mytable
where `key` = 'XXX';
```

Comment: it works, too! Thx Gordon Linoff! and I appreciate your detail post.